# How do I tell cmake where to output its build data?

Tags: c++, c, build-process, cmake

How do I tell cmake where it should output its build data?

Let's say I have a dir with the source code called src/, 
and then since cmake outputs a lot of files I would like him to put all of that in 
a dir called build/.
BUT I would like him to put the generated Makefile in the project root, 
so I don't have to go into the build dir to build the application.

Is this possible with cmake?

I have managed to get the cmake out put if I fun cmake in the build dir like this:

```
cd build/
cmake ../src/
make
./hello
```

But it would be nice to stay in the project root and type something like this

```
cmake
make 
./hello
```

I guess that I need to put a CMakeList.txt in the project root with some magic commands telling him where he could put the object files and where he can find the source code.

Thanks

---

*Update*: 
Since my question is a little bit vague.

After I have run the cmake commands this is how I would like my tree to look like:

```
src/CMakeLists.txt
src/hello.c 
src/hello.h

build/CMakeCache.txt  
build/CMakeFiles/
build/cmake_install.cmake  

CMakeLists.txt
Makefile
```

So the question is how should the CMakeLists.txt look like in this setup.

- CMakeLists.txt
- src/CMakeLists.txt

But maybe that is not possible?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?  I want the exact same thing.

Comment: @meffordm No, I gave up on this idea (and cmake).

Comment: So, what did you end up doing?  Maybe your solution (even without cmake) might be helpful for my project.

Comment: That project was quite small so I stayed with GNU Make, but I was thinking about writing a small "wrapper script" ("build script") and put that in the project root dir.

Comment: I've been pondering the same...maybe a python script so it can be a cross-platform tool.  I just don't like not having control of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BUT I would like him to put the generated Makefile in the project root, so I don't have to go into the build 
>   dir to build the application.

cmake not designed for that, as I know,
BUT you can stay in the project root and type:
make -C build
./hello 
with custom build rules or set_target_properties,
you can force cmake to put result executable to 
sources directory or you can use
./build/hello

Type "cd build && cmake .." you need only once,
after that make will automaticaly start cmake, if something
changed.

Answer (score 0):

`cmake` wants you to have a fresh build directory.

Comment: No problem, my idea was to give cmake that dir to play in all by him self. So the dir called build/ is empty, that would work or?

Comment: no, you should run `make` in the build directory (after running `cmake`as you did in your first example).

Comment: Yes, cmake is intended to be used your first way (at least that is my understanding, but I am not a cmake expert)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i get what you want. I think, you can achieve this with some machinery in CMakeLists.txt. Of course, it's not option if you are not project developer.

In root CMakeLists.txt you can add file(WRITE ...) command, which would write Makefile into ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}. This Makefile would contain these commands for every target:

```
<target>:
  cd ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR} && ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} <target>
```

So, now you can run `make` from source dir and it will build your project in build dir.

Comment: But wait, if I type cmake . && make then the cmake files (CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles/, cmake_install.cmake and CMakeList.txt) would not end up in the build dir, they would be created in the project root dir?

Comment: Right, i thought you are asking exactly about this.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify the question.

Comment: Nope, it's just my english parser fails sometimes, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

Simply use

```
cmake .
make
```

in your src directory. The (.) dot on unix systems addresses the current directory. Keep in mind doing so is actually not recommended since there will be a lot of build files in your src directory you'll have to clean up afterwards or at release time.

Comment: That was not even close to what the question was about, I want to be in the project root and run all the commands. Not in any of the subdirs. But I don't think cmake has any support for this.